# Pass parameters from Django template to view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I **pull** data from an external API and show it in my template. I would like to give users a few options for parameterizing these API requests. What is the best way to go about doing that?

For instance, I am rendering a *game schedule* and I want to let user select the `league` or `date` params and pull from API the data according to user user choice.

view

```py
def games(request):
    """ View to return games page """
    if request.method == "GET":
        day = request.GET.get('date')


    params = {"league": "nba", "date": day}

    results = requests.request("GET", URL, headers=headers, 
                               params=params).json()
```

template with the form for user input:

```
    <form method="GET">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" id="date" name="tomorrow" value=" 
           {{tomorrow|date:'Y-m-d'}}">
       <button class="btn tomorrow-btn light-blue" type="submit">
           Tomorrow's Games
       </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you please share your templates?

Comment: There is nothing really in the template that will pertain to this to show yet. Just a for loop showing all the games. I need to create a form or a button that will pass a date and then receive it in my view.

Comment: I suppose you need use ajax request. You will be able to initiate ajax by button and send anything to your view.

Comment: Your description and example of view code are obscure. Are you asking how to make a **form**? Please show more code and clarify your intent.

Comment: Added my form, just not sure how to make it all work.

Comment: So you have no models, no database, you fetch data from some other website, let user edit it and post changes to that website via api, correct?

Comment: I fetch data from an API and display it in my template for the user.

Comment: and for the second part of my question?.. do you want to post form data to that api?

Comment: Yes. To change the data I am receiving from the API like date or league I need to change the parameters in the view.

Comment: Please don't mention "the view", I'm not asking about your code, I'm asking about the intent which is still unclear. What do you want to do in the end? Post user input to external API, make POST request to _the other website_? Or what? What do you need user input for?

Comment: As I said numerous times earlier... to GET different data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to show the correct answer. I had the wrong form method, should have been GET.

Then I assigned the form value to a variable and passed that variable to the API parameters.